# Cloud Datastore Projection Query with filters with AppEngine NodeJS Standard

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am learning GCP, and have searched through the documentation. The Projection queries documentation states that they can be used with filters albeit with some limitations. As far as I understand I am not falling within the limitations, but still I cannot make it work.

What I want to do is a simple

```
SELECT property FROM kind WHERE enabled = TRUE
```

The properties are marked as indexed, I have also deployed an index.yaml. And my code is the following

```
  const selectQuery = programTypeQuery
     .select(entityNameProperty)
     .filter('enabled',true);
```

When commenting the select line, the query works. When commenting the filter line, it also works, but when running both I get the following message in postman.

```
{
"code": 9,
"metadata": {
    "_internal_repr": {}
},
"note": "Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient"
}
```

My log just shows a 400 status error.

Any help will be appreciated

EDIT:

this is the full code. I have a parameter that indicates the language of the name. in the database I have  nameEn and nameEs as properties, so I want to return only the name in the selected language. enabled is a boolean property that indicates if the product is active or not.

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const datastore = Datastore();
const programTypeQuery = datastore.createQuery('programType')

entityNameProperty = 'name' + req.params.languageCode

const selectQuery = programTypeQuery
.select(entityNameProperty)
.filter('enabled',true);

selectQuery.runQuery()
.then((results) => {
res.json(results);
})
.catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
```

Comment: What are `programTypeQuery` and `entityNameProperty` in your case?

Comment: In the [sample code](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries) there is .createQuery() which is missing in your snippet. Is there specific reason that you discarded it?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I have added the full code

Answer (score 1):

From the details you provided it is hard to detect where this issue is being originated. Can you use [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) for Datastore API and try your query. I prepared the request body according to your descriptions, you can click [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/datastore/datastore/v1/datastore.projects.runQuery?projectId=project-id&_h=1&resource=%257B%250A++%2522query%2522%253A+%250A++%257B%250A++++%2522kind%2522%253A+%250A++++%255B%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522programType%2522%250A++++++%257D%250A++++%255D%252C%250A++++%2522filter%2522%253A+%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522propertyFilter%2522%253A+%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522property%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522enabled%2522%250A++++++++%257D%252C%250A++++++++%2522value%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522booleanValue%2522%253A+true%250A++++++++%257D%252C%250A++++++++%2522op%2522%253A+%2522EQUAL%2522%250A++++++%257D%250A++++%257D%252C%250A++++%2522projection%2522%253A+%250A++++%255B%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522property%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522programTypeNameEn%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%257D%250A++++%255D%250A++%257D%250A%257D&) and execute it by just changing the projectId. By doing this you will receive a sucessful response or an error message with details, it might be easier to detect the root cause from here.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are missing a [composite index definition](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes).  You should be able to look at your GAE logs in stackdriver to see the error message returned from Cloud Datastore.

Since your property name is dynamic you won't be able to use a composite index effectively.  You'll probably need to change your data model to something that doesn't use dynamic property names.

Comment: ok. Checked the composite index in the Cloud Datastore. This is my index:  programTypeNameEn ASC  enabled ASC.

I will forget about using dynamic property names. Changed the code in the .select line to .select("propertyNameEn") and it still gives the same message. In the App Engine log I only found the following: 

"This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."